# How to make new doc tabs appear on the right side?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS2010 there was an option for this, but I can't find it in VS2012. Is it removed? Are there other methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They moved the setting in VS 2012 to:

*Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs*

Comment: Beware that the popular "Productivity Power Tools" extension override this option ordering the tabs alphabetically

Comment: @EduardoMolteni: Yes, but Power Tools provides the option to disable alphabetical ordering, which reverts it to the default behavior in Visual Studio.

Comment: For 2019: `Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Document Tabs > Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs`.

Answer (score -1):

They may have removed this as they've added a feature where transitory tabs appear at the far right. For example, if you browse through the call stack, each file you view will appear here if it isn't already open

Comment: However, when I open files from the solution explorer, they appear at far left.

Comment: Not really much to see about it, but here's a link to a short description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs71dea4.aspx - see the bit that refers to preview tabs