# Let Visual Studio 2012 / 2013 open files to the right instead of to the left

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to let Visual Studio 2012 open the new files to the right instead of to the far left of the open files?

Comment: @-voter comment please?

Comment: Related post - [How to open new doc tab labels on the right side in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388110/465053)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Go to 
`TOOLS` > `Options` > `+ Environment` > `Tabs and Windows` > `Tab Well` > `[x] Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs`

Comment: And for 2010: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents -> "Insert documents to the right of existing tabs". I know the OP is asking about 2012/2013 but I found this link first when wondering about 2010 so I figured I'd post a comment for those who find this looking for 2010.

Comment: For 2019: `Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Document Tabs > Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs`.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** In Visual Studio 2012, if you have the "Productivity Power Tools 2012" installed in your VS extensions, it has features that **override** the standard setting to place new VS document tabs on the right. I discovered this thanks to @davesexton here... [How to make new doc tabs appear on the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399430/how-to-make-new-doc-tabs-appear-on-the-right-side#comment23151086_13312790)

To disable the override by the PPT, go here...

Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > General > Sorting

Uncheck both items:

- By Project
- Alphabetically

There may be more, but that sufficient to make it work for me.